# SQL, What is the total amount each client has paid us?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a little problem here: I've created 5 tables: Customer, Invoice, Line, Product and Vendor.

Task asks me:

> What is the total amount each client has paid us?

And the following comment:

> To find the total amount each client has paid us you need to join
>   customer table with invoice and line. Group by customer code, sum
>   price from line. Balance would only show whether client owes us money.
>   Also when you perform a SUM there should also be a group by statement.

I've made a code, but stuck, because got confused:

```
SELECT Invoice.CUS_CODE
FROM Invoice
    INNER JOIN Customer ON Invoice.CUS_CODE = Customer.CUS_CODE
    WHERE Invoice.INV_NUMBER IN (
    SELECT SUM(Line.LINE_PRICE)
FROM Line
INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.INV_NUMBER = Line.INV_NUMBER
GROUP BY LINE_PRICE)
GROUP BY Invoice.CUS_CODE;
```

So, I need to group INV_NUMBER from Invoice table by CUS_CODE (customer code) from Customer and sum the LINE_PRICE of grouped INV_NUMBER. In the end group by CUS_CODE.

Thank You in advance.

UPD: Tables

Customer table
[image: Customer table]
Line table
[image: Line table]
Invoice table
[image: Invoice table]

Comment: Please simply provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Your comparison of `Invoice.INV_NUMBER` with `SUM(Line.LINE_PRICE)` seems to be really suspicious.

Comment: @Rainman
Customer table:[link](https://i.gyazo.com/1dcc868bfa929ec87f33d04bb55e3fe7.png); Line table:[link](https://i.gyazo.com/c3392ef80fbd17fd44efcb5517b5d88f.png); Invoice table:[link](https://i.gyazo.com/2c1b65f3abc3fe30fac0efa957207e09.png). Desired output should be columns CUS_CODE and LINE_PRICE, according to task

Comment: Ive updated to inline your images - but they are minimally useful. The definitions of your tables and a copyable version of the expected input and output is much better (and will get you an answer). A [mcve] using sqlfiddle or similar would almost guarantee one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are up to simple `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT CUS_CODE, CUS_LNAME, CUS_FNAME, SUM(Line.LINE_PRICE)
FROM Customer 
LEFT JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.CUS_CODE = Customer.CUS_CODE
LEFT JOIN Line ON Invoice.INV_NUMBER = Line.INV_NUMBER
GROUP BY CUS_CODE, CUS_LNAME, CUS_FNAME
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the solution!

Comment: left join is not necessary unless you expect orphans and want to account for them, also add "Having SUM(Line.LINE_PRICE) <> 0" to the end to fill the "Balance would only show whether client owes us money" requirement